# Cómo crear una lista bidimensional a partir de dos listas

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo dos listas y un número variable tal que así:

```py
lista_a=[24, 84, 53, 36, 98, 77, 27, 71, 83, 52]
lista_b=[1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
num=3
```

Con lo de número variable quiero decir que está relacionado con el contenido de "lista_b" de tal forma que esta lista contiene números desde el 1 hasta num. Como en el ejemplo num=3 así es la lista. Por lo tanto varía siempre y "lista_b" lo hace de igual forma (esto hay que tenerlo en cuenta a la hora de hacer el código).

Las dos listas tiene el mismo tamaño y "lista_a" siempre tiene esos elementos, es decir que no cambia como le pasa a "lista_b".

La cosa sería devolver una lista de listas, o una lista bidimensional de tal manera que cada lista contenga los números de "lista_a" según lo marque así en "lista_b".

Para el ejemplo que puse al comienzo el resultado deseado debe ser:

```py
[[24,98,27,52],[36,77,83],[84,53,71]]
```

Pongo lo que, tras muchos cabezazos y probar por probar, he conseguido:

```py
def cruceListas():

    lista_res=[]
    lista_res_2=[]

    for i in range(len(lista_a)):
        lista_res_2[lista_a[lista_b[i]]]

    lista_res.append(lista_res_2)
    return lista_res
```

Actualmente me tira error del tipo "index out of range" pero es cambiar algo y que no me salga la solución.

Comment: Hola! No entiendo muy bien el resultado esperado, pero hay un par de cosas que podrías revisar: lista_res_2.append(lista_a[lista_b[i]]). Con esto, el código funciona (no da error), pero el resultado es: [[84, 36, 36, 53, 84, 53, 84, 36, 53, 84]]. Veo además que no se usa la variable num, no sé si debería.

Comment: Ah, y otra cosa, las listas empiezan en [0]. Es decir, que si en lista_b no hay un cero, el 24 de la lista_a no se seleccionará nunca.

Comment: Hola, me explico mejor sobre el resultado esperado: La "lista_b" digamos que te marca los números de "lista_a" que van en cada lista de la lista bidimensional a devolver. Por ejemplo, si me voy a "lista_b" y digamos, me fijo en los unos, en mi lista bidimensional a devolver ya tengo una lista que contiene todos aquellos números de "lista_a" que también ocupan esos unos en sus posiciones. Siguiendo mi ejemplo: [24,98,27,52] son los números que corresponden a los unos de "lista_b"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh, vale. Ahora lo entiendo.

Prueba esto:

```
lista_a=[24, 84, 53, 36, 98, 77, 27, 71, 83, 52]
lista_b=[1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
num=3

def cruceListas(lista_a, lista_b, num):

    lista_total = []
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        lista_parcial = []
        for j in range(len(lista_b)):
            if lista_b[j] == i:
                lista_parcial.append(lista_a[j])
        lista_total.append(lista_parcial)

    return lista_total

print(cruceListas(lista_a, lista_b, num))
```

Si necesitas entender alguna parte, no dudes en decirlo!

Answer (score 5):

Lo más sencillo puede ser:

- Crear una lista (que será el resultado) que inicialmente contenga 3 listas vacías. O en el caso más general, que contenga `num` listas vacías.
- Iterar *en paralelo* por los elementos de `lista_b` y de `lista_a`. Con "en paralelo" quiero decir usando `zip()`. En cada iteración obtendremos un elemento de `lista_b` y otro de `lista_a`. El primero nos dice a qué sub-lista del resultado ha de ir el segundo. Así que añadimos (con `.append()`) el dato obtenido a la sub-lista en cuestión.

Quizás es más fácil de entender si ves el código, que es muy corto, pues Python es un lenguaje muy expresivo:

```
# Crear la lista que contiene num sub-listas, incialmente vacías
result = [ [] for i in range(num)]

# Iterar en paralelo
for lista, dato in zip(lista_b, lista_a):
  # lista contendrá un número de lista_b como 1, 3, 3, 2, ... 
  # dato contendrá un dato de lista_a como 24, 84, 53, 36, ...
  # Añadimos el dato a la correspondiente sublista
  result[lista-1].append(dato)
```

Al terminar, en `result` tienes lo que buscabas.